# Django ValueError: Related model 'custom_user.customuser' cannot be resolved

Tags: python, django

Получаю постоянно ValueError: Related model 'custom_user.customuser' cannot be resolved
В начале у меня все приложения хранились в папке apps, думал может вопрос в этом. Но по итогу как я не колдовал с бубном, все равно ошибка.
Пример нового приложения users который в корне.
(все миграциии и БД удаленная)

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Telephone', help_text='Формат телефону (xxx) xxx-xxxx',
                                 null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Country', null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='City', null=True, blank=True)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Adress', null=True, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Index', null=True, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Birthday')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users_image/', verbose_name='Photo', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'custom_user'
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    label = "custom_user"
    name = 'users'
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    'users',

    'apps.auth',
    'apps.other',
    'apps.orders',
    'apps.shop',

    'django_cleanup',

]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_user.CustomUser'
```

Comment: А разве в `INSTALLED_APPS` не должно быть `users.apps.UsersConfig`?

Comment: Тут все верно.
Решил проблему со временем.
1) Всем советую дважды проверять label = "custom_user" name = 'users'
2) Моя проблема решилась тем что я создал новый проект и перенес туда весь старый код и все заработало само. Причина ошибки так и осталась неизвестная... Возможно проблема была в переменных окружения или в самом виртуально окружении..